# Flume syslogtcp source using rsyslog

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, flume-ng

I need to ingest data from remote server using flume to hdfs::

I have used source as syslogtcp. My flume.conf file is as:

```
Agent.sources = syslog
Agent.channels = MemChannel
Agent.sinks = HDFS

Agent.sources.syslog.type = syslogtcp
Agent.sources.syslog.channels = MemChannel
Agent.sources.syslog.port = 5140
Agent.sources.syslog.host = localhost

Agent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
Agent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://192.168.111.130:8022/user/cloudera/Twitter/apple_data/%y/%m/%d/
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
Agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

Agent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
Agent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
Agent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I have a file in /etc/rsyslog.d/B2B.conf

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

#$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
#$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad imfile

$InputFileName /home/cloudera/Desktop/my_logs/my_log.txt
$InputFileTag tag1:
$InputFileStateFile stat-file1

$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollingInterval 10
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
*.* @@192.168.111.130:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

Now when I run the java application to create log, flume and rsyslog:

It halts at

Shutting down system logger:
Starting system logger:

Comment: So rsyslog doesn't start? Can you stop it and start it in foreground (rsyslog -n) or in debug mode (rsyslog -dn) to see if you get any clues? Also, with a recent version of rsyslog you can output to HDFS directly (via HTTP): http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omhttpfs.html

Comment: Any ways now I am doing this through ntecat source